# Trouble with an unprivilaged users in a chroot under Debian

Tags: debian, chroot

I'm having trouble with users in a chroot under Debian GNU/Linux.

I have created a chroot for the stable distribution using debootstrap.

I enter the chroot by using the following script

```
#!/bin/sh -v
mount proc /debian-new/proc -t proc
mount sysfs /debian-new/sys -t sysfs
mount --bind /dev /debian-new/dev
mount --make-rslave /debian-new/sys 
mount --bind /dev/pts /debian-new/dev/pts
mount --rbind /dev /debian-new/dev 
mount --make-rslave /debian-new/dev
chroot debian-new /bin/bash
```

I've copied the files /etc/password /etc/shadow /etc/group from the main system in my chroot

But when trying to change to an unprivilaged user I get:

```
# su pablo
Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
```

(inside the chroot)

Also apt-get install prints this warning message

W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.13-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Please help me!

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /bin/bash`?

Comment: Is `/debian-new` mounted `noexec?

Comment: No. It is part of the main filesystem. Where all the /home directories are...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason. The directory of the chroot was owned by root.
Others didn't have read permission over it.